# Accessing class instance in swift

Tags: ios, swift, instance, swift-class

I've got a Graph class which is an UIView and I'm initializing it inside `mainVC.swift`:

```
class MainVC : UIViewController{
   let graph : Graph!

   override func viewDidLoad(){
      super.viewDidLoad()
      let data_x : [Double] = [...]
      let data_y : [Double] = [...]
      ...
      graph = Graph(frame: CGRect(...), color: ..., xData: data_x, yData: data_y, darkMode: ...)
      view.addSubview(graph)
      ...
      }
```

Now I would like to access function inside instance of the class which I've created in MainVC in different class (to populate data in TableView).

`var g : Graph = MainVC.graph` returns "Instance member graph cannot be used on type MainVC"
I've also tried using static variable but there was an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the way which i known check it out.

```
class MainVC {
   let graph : Graph! 
}
```

graph is a stored property is a constant or variable that is **stored as part of an instance of a particular class**.So you tried for accessing instance property not an instance of class.

In your class MainVC make variable as static which holds instance

```
 static var graph: Graph?
```

Then store instance of Graph in graph property in Graph class

```
  MainVc.graph = self
```

Now you can use in another class where you access graph instance like

```
  MainVc.graph
```

Comment: @codddeer123 glad to help if it's useful then you can accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing an instance variable on a class, not an instance of it.

Comment: so this variable doesn't hold a reference to the instance of this class? How should I do it then?

Answer (score 0):

```
let mainVc = MainVC()
let graph = self.graph
```

Comment: then try graph = self.graph,